# Removing Span tags in navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working on a custom Magento theme and I am stumped on how to remove the `span class` in the navigation.

I found the file which has it:

Mage => Page => Block => Html => Topmenu.php

I found the `span` which is in the `<A> link` but in the header of the file it says not to edit the file in case of a overwrite when updating.

Where would I place this file in my own theme's directory?

Thanks for any help.

Ben :)

P.S. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: you can rewrite the topmenu.php, or copy the folder structure to local code pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to write your own module, where you will override the Topmenu.php Block Class.

If you dont know how to setup a basic module structure in Magento, i highly recommend you to read some Tuts about it. There are also some great Tutorials about Block override in the web. Just search for "Magento Block override".

Comment: Thanks for this, I have checked it out and indeed used it :)